# How to use \owedge and \boxwedge

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages, math-operators

We can use symbols of

`$\otimes$ and $\boxtimes$, $\oplus$ and $\boxplus$, $\ominus$ and $\boxminus$`

in Latex.

However, do we have `$\owedge$` and `$\boxwedge$`, which combines `$\wedge$` in the mid of a `$O$` and a box? If yes how, if not, how could we define it?

Thank you so much for the experts here!!! (I received great comments from many of you.)

Comment: The package `stmaryrd` contains `\owedge` command which is probably what you need, but I don't know of `\boxwedge` so far.

Comment: Indeed, I found the \owedge I wish: http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~texmf/installed/texmf-var/doc/latex/stmaryrd/stmaryrd.pdf. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example defines `\boxwedge` and `\owedge` using TikZ:

- The symbols adapt in size and line width according to the current math style.
- They are defined as binary operators like `\boxplus` and `\oplus`.
- The height, width/side bearings are derived from `\boxplus` and `\oplus`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\boxwedge}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@boxwedge{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@boxwedge}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\boxplus\m@th$}%
  \dimen2=.5\dimexpr\wd0-\ht0-\dp0\relax % side bearing
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
  \def\lw{.06}% linw width as factor for height of \boxplus
  \kern\dimen2 % side bearing
  \tikz[
    line width=\lw\dimen@,
    line join=round,
    x=\dimen@,
    y=\dimen@,
  ]
  \draw
    (\lw/2,0) rectangle (1-\lw,1-\lw)
    (\lw,0) -- (.5,1-\lw-\lw/2) -- (1-\lw-\lw/2 ,0)
  ;%
  \kern\dimen2 % side bearing
}
\makeatletter

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\owedge}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@owedge{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@owedge}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\oplus\m@th$}%
  \dimen2=.5\dimexpr\wd0-\ht0-\dp0\relax % side bearing
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
  \def\lw{.04}% line width as factor for height of \oplus
  \def\radius{.5-\lw/2}%
  \kern\dimen2 % side bearing
  \tikz[
    line width=\lw\dimen@,
    line join=round,
    x=\dimen@,
    y=\dimen@,
    baseline=\dimexpr-.5\dimen@+\dp0\relax,
  ]
  \draw
    (0,0) circle[radius=\radius]
    % -36.87 = -90 + 2 atan(1/2)
    % 216.87 = 180 + 36.87
    (225:\radius) -- (0,.5-\lw) -- (-45:\radius)
  ;%
  \kern\dimen2 % side bearing  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \boxplus\boxwedge_{\boxplus\boxwedge_{\boxplus\boxwedge}}
\]
\[
  \oplus\owedge_{\oplus\owedge_{\oplus\owedge}}
\]
% Check bounding box
\[
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
  \fbox{$\boxplus$}\fbox{$\boxwedge$}
  \fbox{$\owedge$}
  \fbox{$\oplus$}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is amazing. It looks really nice!!! +1. (Yours will be the answer if nothing comes out better.)