Putting a circle around the wedge
since the tensor notation is sometimes (not mathematically, but visually) somewhat not that immeditate to read, especially when logical and algebraic notations are mixed, I was trying to differentiate all tensor notations with a circle around: there are already $\otimes$ and $\odot$, but now I would also like to have a sort of "\owedge", hence the WEDGE symbol inside of a CIRCLE, as the other ones.
Can someone please help? Thank you in advance.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. In your case it could also be helpful to show a sketch of the wanted result.

Just searching \owedge on this site yields some results, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172564/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358717/82917. And if you are using standard fonts, the package stmaryrd provides \owedge directly.

Very kind thank you.

Following the suggestion of the comments of the user @campa use stmaryrd package.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd}
\begin{document}

\[\text{Computer modern font } f^{\varowedge} \varowedge g= \alpha\owedge \beta a_{\owedge}, \]
\end{document}



Very kind thank you.

I'm not sure whether importing a single glyph is meaningful in this case. You are using up a math alphabet anyway, and the symbols of stmaryrd  harmonize with amssymb by design, so I'd just load stmaryrd...

@campa Approved!
